How to control plot size whith different legend size matplotlib
I want to have 2 plots of the same size. The size of the figure is not as important.
The only change I am making is to the length of the labels.
(In reallity I have 2 related data sets )
A long label causes the plot to deform. How can I avoid this? I need 2 coherent plots.

import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

def my_plot(x,ys,labels, size = (5.75, 3.2)):
    fig, ax1 = plt.subplots(nrows=1, ncols=1, sharex=True,  
                            figsize=size,
                            dpi = 300)

    ax1.plot(x, ys[0], label = labels[0])
    ax1.plot(x, ys[1], label = labels[1])

    ## Add ticks, axis labels and title
    ax1.set_xlim(0,21.1)
    ax1.set_ylim(-50,50)
    ax1.tick_params(axis='both', which='major', labelsize=18)
    ax1.set_xlabel('Time', size = 18)
    ax1.set_ylabel('Angle', size = 18)

    ## Add legend outside the plot
    ax1.legend(ncol=1, bbox_to_anchor=(1, 0.5), loc='center left', edgecolor='w')
    

# Dummy data
x1 = np.arange(0, 24, 0.1)
y1_1 = np.sin(x1)*45
y1_2 = np.cos(x1)*25

my_plot(x1, [y1_1, y1_2], ["sin", "cos", "tan"])
my_plot(x1, [y1_1, y1_2], ["long_sin", "long_cos", "long_tan"])

resulting in the following two plots:
plot 1:

plot 2:

I have tried:

plt.tight_layout()
ax1.set_aspect(0.1)
changing size of subplots - which almost solves the issue, but not quite, as all the effective font sizes change.

to be clear I want the plots to be separated (to be later saved in 2 files)

Do you require that the two plots are on separate figures, or can they be in the same figure object?

They need to be on separate figures. But I might use this approach and split them in an editor if I won't find a better way.

@FrankMusterman If you require separate figures, then surely just using the windows that are generated from matplotlib and stretching/ resizing them will achieve your goal. I will give separate plots an attempt now though anyway.

Edited answer to include separated plots as well as the single plot with subfigures.

Very similarly to EuanG's answer, within your my_plot function, you can create a figure with two columns and add the plot to the left hand column and the legend to the right hand one. You can then adjust the width ratios until your legend fits without changing the size of the plots in the left hand axes:
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

def my_plot(x,ys,labels, size = (5.75, 3.2)):
    fig, axs = plt.subplots(nrows=1, ncols=2, sharex=True,  
                            figsize=size, width_ratios=[4, 2],
                            dpi=300)

    l1, = axs[0].plot(x, ys[0], label=labels[0])
    l2, = axs[0].plot(x, ys[1], label=labels[1])

    ## Add ticks, axis labels and title
    axs[0].set_xlim(0,21.1)
    axs[0].set_ylim(-50,50)
    axs[0].tick_params(axis='both', which='major', labelsize=18)
    axs[0].set_xlabel('Time', size = 18)
    axs[0].set_ylabel('Angle', size = 18)

    ## Add legend to right plot grid
    axs[1].legend(handles=[l1, l2], ncol=1, edgecolor="w", loc="center left")
    axs[1].axis("off")


# Dummy data
x1 = np.arange(0, 24, 0.1)
y1_1 = np.sin(x1)*45
y1_2 = np.cos(x1)*25

my_plot(x1, [y1_1, y1_2], ["sin", "cos", "tan"])
my_plot(x1, [y1_1, y1_2], ["long_sin", "long_cos", "long_tan"])


This can be achieved with matplotlib GridSpec:
from matplotlib.gridspec import GridSpec

Single Image two plots
By creating a grid for the subplots you can control the sizes. The layout is a grid with two rows and two columns. One column is reserved for the legends/ labels so that they do not interfere with the size of the main plots.
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(10, 8), dpi=100)
gs = GridSpec(2, 2, width_ratios=[1, 0.3], height_ratios=[1, 1], wspace=0.3, hspace=0.4)

# First plot (Top)
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(gs[0, 0])
my_plot(ax1, x1, [y1_1, y1_2], ["sin", "cos"])

# Second plot (Bottom) with longer labels
ax2 = fig.add_subplot(gs[1, 0])
my_plot(ax2, x1, [y1_1, y1_2], ["long_sine_label", "long_cosine_label"])


Two Separate Figures
As two seperate figures is requested in comment you can achieve this with GridSpec in the same way except now just use two of them for separate figures. Now you have 1 row 2 columns (times 2).
# ------------------ First Figure: Short Labels ------------------
fig1 = plt.figure(figsize=(10, 6), dpi=100)
gs1 = GridSpec(1, 2, figure=fig1, width_ratios=[4, 1], wspace=0.3)

# Plot Axis
ax1_plot = fig1.add_subplot(gs1[0, 0])

# Legend Axis
ax1_legend = fig1.add_subplot(gs1[0, 1])

# Plot and Legend
my_plot(ax1_plot, ax1_legend, x1, [y1_1, y1_2], ["sin", "cos"])

# ------------------ Second Figure: Long Labels ------------------
fig2 = plt.figure(figsize=(10, 6), dpi=100)
gs2 = GridSpec(1, 2, figure=fig2, width_ratios=[4, 1], wspace=0.3)

# Plot Axis
ax2_plot = fig2.add_subplot(gs2[0, 0])

# Legend Axis
ax2_legend = fig2.add_subplot(gs2[0, 1])


Both figures are now the same size.
